# c++ and fastcgi - upstream closed prematurely FastCGI stdout while reading response header from upstream

Tags: c++, nginx, fastcgi

I am using nginx, factcgi and spawn-fcgi and trying to get it to work.

I start spawn-fcgi as follows:

```
g++ rtbTimeSeries.cpp -o forecast.fcgi -I/home/ubuntu/cpp/boost_1_52_0/ -I/home/ubuntu/cpp/NR_C301/ -lfcgi++ -lfcgi
spawn-fcgi -a 127.0.0.1 -p 8010 -n forecast.fcgi
```

When I go to

```
http://127.0.0.1:83/forecast.fcgi
```

I get a 502 error

When I look can the output of spawn-fcgi fron the command line I see the correct output...see the very bottom of the post:

In the nginx logs I get this:

```
2013/02/21 19:42:39 [error] 16342#0: *39 upstream closed prematurely FastCGI stdout while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /forecast.fcgi HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:8010", host: "127.0.0.1:83"
```

Here is my c++ code:

```
int main() {
    FCGX_Init();
    while(FCGI_Accept() >= 0){
        printf("Content-type: text/html\r\n"
                       "\r\n"

                       "<title>FastCGI Hello!</title>"
                       "<h1>FastCGI Hello!</h1>"
                       "Request number %d running on host <i>%s</i>\n",
                        ++count, getenv("SERVER_NAME"));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my nginx.conf section:

```
server {
              listen 83;
              server_name 127.0.0.1;

             location / {
          fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:8010;

          fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
          fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx;
          fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
          fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
          fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
          fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;
          fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
          fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
          fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
          fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
          fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
          fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
          fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
          fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
          fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
          fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
          fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
        }


    }
```

Below is the output from the console when I hit the url in the browser.

```
spawn-fcgi -a 127.0.0.1 -p 8010 -n forecast.fcgi
Content-Type: text/plain

Hello world in C
Content-type: text/html

<title>FastCGI Hello!</title><h1>FastCGI Hello!</h1>Request number 1 running on host <i>127.0.0.1</i>
Content-Type: text/plain

Hello world in C
Content-type: text/html

<title>FastCGI Hello!</title><h1>FastCGI Hello!</h1>Request number 2 running on host <i>127.0.0.1</i>
Content-Type: text/plain

Hello world in C
Content-type: text/html

<title>FastCGI Hello!</title><h1>FastCGI Hello!</h1>Request number 3 running on host <i>127.0.0.1</i>
Content-Type: text/plain

Hello world in C
Content-type: text/html

<title>FastCGI Hello!</title><h1>FastCGI Hello!</h1>Request number 4 running on host <i>127.0.0.1</i>
Content-Type: text/plain

Hello world in C
Content-type: text/html

<title>FastCGI Hello!</title><h1>FastCGI Hello!</h1>Request number 5 running on host <i>127.0.0.1</i>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to #include "fcgi_stdio.h"?

If I was writing an app from scratch, I'd use FCGI_printf explicitly instead of relying on the #define magic in fcgi_stdio.h.